# Webhook PHP with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have this code for my webhook stripe

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("you_api_key");

$postdata = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event = json_decode($postdata);
if ($event->type == 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
    $customer_id = $event->data->object->customer;
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
    $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($event->data->object->id);

    // This is where we'd normally e-mail the invoice, but we'll just write out the invoice to a file instead.
    $from = "From: Me";
    $to = "To: ".$customer->email;
    $subject = "Subject: You have made a payment for another month of Wilde quotes";
    $body = "You have made a new payment for $".($invoice->total / 100.0).":\n\n";

    foreach($invoice->lines->data as &$line) {
        if ($line->type == 'subscription') {
            $body .= "Subscription - ".$line->plan->name.": ".$line->amount."\n";
        }
        else if ($line->type == 'invoiceitem') {
            $body .= "Additional -".$line->description.": ".$line->amount;
        }
    }

    $email_file = fopen($customer->id."-".$invoice->date, 'a');
    $email = $from."\n".$to."\n".$subject."\n".$body;
    fwrite($email_file, $email);
}
```

My question is, how to receive email subscription or email charge or other by webhook stripe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which events your webhook retrieves is determined by your settings in the Stripe dashboard.

I'd recommend receiving all event types and using an if statement as you have in you code to react to the events you're interested in. Make sure your application always returns a `200 OK` status or Stripe will retry webhooks.

There's an example of sending emails in response to failed payments here:
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments

A list of all events sent by Stripe is here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#event_types

If you have specific implementation questions, or are getting error messages, I'd recommend emailing Stripe support as they can help you directly with questions about your code and your account.